# Need to word-wrap text in C

Tags: c, word-wrap

Well i have simple homework. I receive text from teacher server and need to make it look like chat. Some text is on left side some on right side. That is what i have done and work.

```
i = 0;
ratac = 0;

int padding = 1;
while (recvbuf[i] != '\0') {
    if (ratac == 61) {
        padding = 1;
        ratac = 0;
    }

    if (padding) {
        printf("%+60c", recvbuf[i]);
        padding = 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("%c", recvbuf[i]);
    }
    ratac++;
    i++;

};
```

But i need to add word wrap and dont know how to do it. (one word cant be on two lines). Know it looke like this

```
                                       WORD WORD WORD WO
                                       RD WORD WORD WORD
```

And I need to make it looks like this

```
                                   WORD WORD WORD 
                                   WORD WORD WORD
                                   WORD
```

Thank for any help.

Comment: What is the `+` for in `"%+60c"`?  It is only relevant to integer values (to force an explicit +/- sign).  It is not the opposite of `-` (left justify), since right-justification is the default.

Comment: Actually a complex subject, especially when you get into hyphenation. https://xxyxyz.org/line-breaking/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you need first to check there is enough place before to write a word

supposing

- the separator are only spaces
- all the separators are produced (even consecutively or at the beginning of a line)
- in case a word is longer than the width it is not cut (case of *azeryuiop* in the execution later)

a proposal from your code where the program receives in argument the left margin, the width and the string

```
#include <stdio.h>

int length(char * p)
{
  char * p2 = p;

  while (*(++p2) && *p2 != ' ')
    ;

  return (int)(p2 - p);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 4) {
    printf("Usage : %s <left margin> <width> <string>\n", *argv);
    return -1;
  }

  int margin, width;

  if ((sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &margin) != 1) || (margin < 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid margin\n");
    return -1;
  }
  if ((sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &width) != 1) || (width < 1)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid width\n");
    return -1;
  }

  char *  recvbuf = argv[3];

  int i = 0;
  int ratac = width;

  while (recvbuf[i] != '\0') {
    if (ratac >= width) {
      if (i) 
        putchar('\n');
      for (int j = 0; j != margin; ++j)
        putchar(' ');
      ratac = 0;
    }

    if (recvbuf[i] == ' ') {
      putchar(' ');
      i += 1;
      ratac += 1;
    }
    else {
      int len = length(recvbuf + i);

      if (((ratac + len) <= width) || (ratac == 0)) {
        ratac += len;
        while (len--)
          putchar(recvbuf[i++]);
      }
      else
        ratac = width;
    }
  }
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra p.c
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out 2 7 "a zer az e r az e aze azeryuiop aze" 
  a zer 
  az e r 
  az e 
  aze 
  azeryuiop
   aze
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to know the size of the complete word.
In order to do that try to change your code in a way to find a complete word (using spaces)and then decide if it fits in the current line or you need a new line